# Issue when using a DAO handle when the database closes unexpectedly

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, dao

I am using a DAO handle (represented in the below code) to improve the speed and performance of my Access database which is found on a shared network and is quite slow. The below code was offered to me by an expert to help the database improve it's speed and performance. As you can see, the database upon opening opens the handle (OpenAllDatabases True), and then closes it upon closing the database (OpenAllDatabases False).

My issue arrives when the database unexpectedly closes. When this happens, I am then informed that i no longer can get into edit mode of the database because it is already opened by another user. I imagine that this is the case because the the 'OpenAllDatabases' was set to TRUE when the database unexpectedly closed.  When this happens, i am forced to open the database in exclusive only deactive the code, close and re-open the database and then rebuild the code.  This for me is quite risky especially since there are multiple users using the tool.   Below is my code:

On the main form:

```
Form_Load()
  OpenAllDatabases True
End Sub
```

On the command buttons to close the database:

```
Private Sub cmdCloseDatabase_Click()
  OpenAllDatabases False
End Sub
```

Module

```
Sub OpenAllDatabases(pfInit As Boolean)
    ' Open a handle to all databases and keep it open during the entire time the application runs.
    ' Params  : pfInit   TRUE to initialize (call when application starts)
    '                    FALSE to close (call when application ends)
    ' Source  : Total Visual SourceBook

    Dim x As Integer
    Dim strName As String
    Dim strMsg As String

    ' Maximum number of back end databases to link
    Const cintMaxDatabases As Integer = 2

    ' List of databases kept in a static array so we can close them later
    Static dbsOpen() As DAO.Database

    If pfInit Then
        ReDim dbsOpen(1 To cintMaxDatabases)
        For x = 1 To cintMaxDatabases
            ' Specify your back end databases
            Select Case x
                Case 1:
                    strname="S:\Apps\PRESTO\BE.accdb"
            End Select
            strMsg = ""

    On Error Resume Next
            Set dbsOpen(x) = OpenDatabase(strName)
            If Err.Number > 0 Then
                strMsg = "Trouble opening database: " & strName & vbCrLf & _
                         "Make sure the drive is available." & vbCrLf & _
                         "Error: " & Err.Description & " (" & Err.Number & ")"
            End If

    On Error GoTo 0
            If strMsg <> "" Then
                MsgBox strMsg
                Exit For
            End If
        Next x
    Else
    On Error Resume Next
        For x = 1 To cintMaxDatabases
            dbsOpen(x).Close
        Next x
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, thanks for fixing that issue.

I use similar code, which works all the time.  I have been comparing your code to mine, and trying to think what the difference could be.

The next thing I would like for you to try is change this line:

```
Set dbsOpen(x) = OpenDatabase(strName)
```

To:

```
Set dbsOpen(x) = OpenDatabase(strName, ReadOnly:=True)
```

In my quick tests, this will still improve the performance of the application, and your forms can still write to the backend data.

This way, `OpenAllDatabases` cannot get a write lock on your backend database. See if this solves the issue when your frontend closes unexpectedly.

Answer (score 2):

In `Sub OpenAllDatabases`, I see a problem with these two lines:

```
Const cintMaxDatabases As Integer = 2
' ...
For x = 1 To cintMaxDatabases
    Select Case x
        Case 1:
            strname="S:\Apps\PRESTO\BE.accdb"
    End Select
```

You are going through the loop twice, but are only setting the database path once. If you follow your code, you are making TWO connections to "S:\Apps\PRESTO\BE.accdb".

Fix this error so you are only making one connection, and see if your problem goes away.

Comment: Kismert, thanks for that. I fixed it.   But it still doesnt seem to resolve my issue; when the database closes unexpectedly, I no longer can make edits to it without opening it in exclusive mode and then i have to disable the 'on  load' handle open, reopen the database, and then close it.